# How to disable vim's indentation of switch case?

Tags: c, indentation, vim

I'm currently fighting with Vim, I can't seem to make the indentation options do what I want.

Here are my settings, I put them at the bottom of .vimrc to make sure they take precedence. As you can see I'm going a little crazy, so I tried turning off almost everything:

```
set cindent
set cinkeys=o,O
set cinoptions=
set cinwords=
set indentexpr=
```

In most cases it seems to work fine, it does one indent after opening a block and everything is fine. But there is one case that is driving me crazy, when there is a `{` after a `case` statement, the next line is way too far indented:

```
switch () {
    case CASE: {
                   // <-- next line gets indented to here, why??
        // <-- should be indented to here
```

How can I make it stop doing this? TIA

Comment: In case you're curious, the strange behavior is intended to let you write one statement on the same line as the case, with additional statements aligned with the first, for example,  `case CASE: x = 1;` ¶ `y = 2;` where x and y are in the same column.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
:set cinoptions=l1
```

(that's the letter ell followed by a number one)

Look at :help cinoptions-values for the default string and descriptions of the different options.

Answer (score 1):

When I manually key in your `set` commands, I get no indentation whatsoever.  Have you looked at the output of `:set all` to confirm your settings are not being overridden?

Note:  This should probably be in a comment, but that option is presently disallowed to me.

Comment: I had a feeling something fishy was going on, but I don't see anything surprising when looking at `:set all`. Maybe it uses its own secret default when I leave those options blank? Don't know..

Comment: Interestingly when I first tried it I was using GVim 7.2.269 on Windows.  When I tried again using 7.2.330 under Linux my results matched your OP.

Answer (score 1):

If indent is N spaces (replace N with actual value), try the following

```
set cinoptions=p0,t0,:N,=0
set cinwords=if,else,switch,case,for,while,do
set cindent
```

:N -> place 'case' label 0 characters from switch's indent

=0 -> indents the statements within case label